# bug in c++ program count no of 1's in vector

Tags: c++, vector

A question was asked to me during an online interview.
They provided a piece of code and we have to find out a possible bug in the code.
The code is provided below as it is.

1. The function is provided with a non empty zero indexed vector of integers (which contains only 1 and 0).
2. The function will return the start position of longest sequence of 1's.
   for example if the input values `{0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1}` it will return `3` because the longest sequence of 1's is from position 3 to 7 total five consecutive 1's.
   if the input values are `{0,0,1}` then it will return `2` because there is only one 1 and length of longest sequence of 1 is one.
3. If there are no 1's then it will return `-1`.
4. The input vector can be changed so we can't change the signature of the vector to const.

I tested this function with variable no of inputs and I found out that it is working fine.
I am not able to find out any bug in the code. But the instruction says that there is a bug in the code and we can change maximum 2 lines of code to solve the bug.

```
int solution(vector<int>& A) {
    int n = A.size();
    int i = n - 1;
    int result = -1;
    int k = 0;
    int maximal = 0;
    while (i > 0) {
        if (A[i] == 1) {
            k = k + 1;
            if (k >= maximal) {
                maximal = k;
                result = i;
            }
        } else {
            k = 0;
        }
        i = i - 1;
    }
    if (A[i] == 1 && k + 1 > maximal)
        result = 0;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This looks like an school assignment... What is your question?

Comment: Do you have a question? It looks you're asking us to debug and solve this for you.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`) to understand what is happening.

Comment: I think nobody able to understand the question. This function is working fine according to me. I ran many test cases but not able to figure out what's the problem in the code, but the question says that there is some bug in the code.  I saw this question in codility.

Comment: Well the first issue I can see is that the first element is never compared

Comment: UB when `A` is empty().

Comment: The result for `{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}` (2) is correct but unintuitive.

Comment: The first element is compared at third last line.The vector will never be empty.

Answer (score 0):

To fix UB for empty case, I add check for `!A.empty()`,
and I profit of that to replace `i` by `0` (at that point `i == 0`)
and to replace the check with maximal value to have a coherent result for tie:

```
if (!A.empty() && A[0] == 1 && k + 1 >= maximal)
```

And as I may change an other line, I would fix the prototype as `A` is not modified.

```
int solution(const std::vector<int>& A) {
```

Answer (score 0):

problem specifications are that

1.vector is immutable and
2.Input vector is not empty

I tried same problem in Java but different approach to see what is missing because i cant find any bug in above code.

package javaapplication7;

/**
 *
 * @author Owner
 */
public class JavaApplication7 {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int[] A={0,1,0,1,1,1,1};
    System.out.println(solution(A));
}

static int solution(int A[]){
    int i=0,count=0,max=0,pos=-1;
while(i<=A.length-1)
{

 if(A[i]==1)
 {
     count++;
     i=i+1;
 }  
    else
 {
     i=i+1;
     count=0;
 }
 if(count>max)
 {
     pos=i-count;
     max=count;
 }
}
if(count==0)
return pos;
else 
    return pos; 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

the given code will favor a sequence closer to the left side if two sequences are of equal length. that doesn't happen for the checking of index 0

```
if (A[i] == 1 && k + 1 > maximal)
```

should be

```
if (A[i] == 1 && k + 1 >= maximal)
```